# dpkg Errors were encountered while processing

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, deb

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my PC. I currently have a file `A.deb`. I want to install this file:

If I do this:

```
dpkg -i A.deb
```

Output :

```
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
brahim@DrBrm:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -i A.deb 
[sudo] password for brahim: 
(Reading database ... 274903 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack A.deb ...
Unpacking texmaker (4.5) over (4.5) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'A.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive A.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/texmaker/doc13hu.png' to '/usr/share/texmaker/doc13hu.png.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 A.deb
```

How do I install this file?

Answer (score 2):

The file appears to be corrupted, it's not an installation issue.

Delete the file, redownload it, and try to `dpkg` it again.

Comment: i'm redownload 5 Times